# Clearing "/var/log/journal"

Tags: debian, log-files, debian-jessie, journald

I want to clear my "/var/log/journal" directory.

I'm using debian 8

```
root@nyc3-x8:/var/log# uname -a
Linux nyc3-x8 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.36-1+deb8u2 (2016-10-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

And my journal;

```
root@nyc3-x8:/var/log# du -hs journal/
11G journal/
```

I searched the forum and tried "journalctl --vacuum-time = xd" but it didn't work;

```
root@nyc3-x8:/var/log# journalctl --vacuum-time=1d
journalctl: unrecognized option '--vacuum-time=1d'
```

What should i do?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `/etc/systemd/journald.conf` to make the retention time shorter or limit the file size.

`MaxRetentionSec=` can specify the time to keep logs in seconds. You can override the default unit of time by using a value like "1month" or "1y"

`SystemMaxUse=` accepts percentage values, and defaults to 10%.

If changing these options and restarting don't make a difference (apparently corrupted logs will never be deleted), you can safely delete anything in the `/var/log/journal` directory with `rm`, just don't delete the directory itself.

Answer (score 0):

It should be 
`journalctl --vacuum-time 1d`.

Comment: same result;

`root@nyc3-x8:/var/log# journalctl --vacuum-time 1d
journalctl: unrecognized option '--vacuum-time'`

Comment: Did you try this?
https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/184348/280841

Comment: Yes, nothing has changed.

Comment: Interesting.  The above command works for me.  Maybe it's about different versions of journalctl?